# Upload file to ftp with crontab using cygwin and curl

Tags: curl, ftp, cygwin

I have a problem with uploading a file to a ftp server using bash script, which I try to run on cygwin

The script looks as follows:

```
#!\bin\bash
date="$(date +%Y_%j -d "5 day ago")"
file="C:/directory/${date}filename with spaces.tsf"
### Upload file to ftp
curl --user user:psw --upload-file "$file" ftp://server/directory/
```

The output is: `'!rl: Can't open 'C:/directory/2019_317filename with spaces.tsf`

On the other hand, running curl from command line and uploading the same file to the same ftp server works just fine

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

In cygwin is better to use UNIX/Linux path format. Try to format the name of the file on this way:

```
 file="/cygdrive/c/directory/${date}filename with spaces.tsf"
```

Comment: it doesn't work. curl from cygwin console works with "C:/directory/..." but it doesn't work when put into script

Comment: You can try with `set -x` and redirect the output of the script to log file to check what happen

Comment: Verify that you are using the cygwin's curl. Issue `curl --version`. The first part of first line should be: "curl 7.65.3 (x86_64-pc-cygwin) ". Then try running your script from the bash prompt, e.g. `./script.sh`. Add echo in front of curl to see what the command line looks like. BTW, the shebang line should be `#!/bin/bash`.